# Custom List Accordian Narrative editable

Tags: rest, query, api

I am looking to enable the Narrative porition of this code to be editable.

```
<!-- Style -->
<style type="text/css">
.item-title-clickable{
    font-size:1.1em;
    background-color: #c7e0f4;
    padding:2px 5px;
    margin-top:2px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.item-narrative{
    display: none;
    border-right:3px #c7e0f4 solid;
    border-bottom:3px #c7e0f4 solid;
    border-left:3px #c7e0f4 solid;
    padding:3px;
}
</style>
<!-- HTML placeholder -->
<div id="faq_placeholder"></div>
<!-- Script -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function getFaqItems(){
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "/WEB_BASE_URL/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('LIST_NAME')/items",
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/jsom;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": document.getElementById("__REQUESTDIGEST").value
        }
    }).done(function (data) {
        var b = [];
        jQuery.each(data.d.results,function(i,item){
            b.push("<div class='item-title-clickable' onclick='jQuery(this).next().slideToggle(100);'>"+item.Title+"</div>");
            b.push("<div class='item-narrative'>"+item.Narrative+"</div>");
        });
        jQuery("#faq_placeholder").html(b.join(""));
    }).fail(function (err) {
        jQuery("#faq_placeholder").html(JSON.stringify(err));
    });
}
// Call function
getFaqItems();
</script>
</code>
```

I am at a loss of how to accomplish this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace with below portion while creating html:

```
    b.push("<div class='item-narrative'>"+item.Narrative+"<input type='text' style='height:80px;width:100%;' value='"+item.Narrative+"' /></br></div>");
});
```